# probability density

Tags: probability

You throw a dart randomly at a board of radius 12 inches. If it lands within 4 inches of the center you get 3 points, if between 4 and 8 inches you get 2 points, and you get one point otherwise (call this number $A$).

You then choose a number from the interval $[0,10]$ with density $f_{B}(b) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{60}(b + 1)$. Let $X = A + B$.

A. Find $\operatorname{P}(A = 3|X > 5).$

B. Find $\operatorname{E}(X)$.

On a study guide for a test and I'm not really sure where to even begin. If someone could help me with the first steps and then work through it with me that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: $fB(b)$ is supposed to be $f(b)$?

Comment: The B is supposed to be sub script. Sorry I'm not particularly familiar with formatting on here so its f sub B(b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Consider the possibilities: $A \in \{1,2,3\}$ so that, for $X \gt 5$, one of the following must be true: $A=3$ and $B \gt 2$, $A=2$ and $B \gt 3$, or $A=1$ and $B \gt 4$.  Now,

$$P(A=3|X \gt 5) = \frac{P(A=3 \cap X > 5)}{P(X \gt 5)}$$

Now, I assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent RVs.  Therefore, we may write this probability as

$$P(A=3|X \gt 5) = \frac{P(A=3)P(B \gt 2)}{P(A=1)P(B \gt 4)+P(A=2)P(B \gt 3)+P(A=3)P(B \gt 2)}$$

Now we compute these probabilities, which I assume you can handle.  I get

$$P(A=3|X \gt 5) = \frac{\frac19 \frac{14}{15}}{\frac{5}{9} \frac{4}{5}+\frac13 \frac{7}{8}+\frac19 \frac{14}{15}}=\frac{112}{907}$$

(b)

$$E(X)=E(A)+E(B)$$

$$E(A) = \frac{5}{9}\cdot 1+\frac13 \cdot 2 + \frac19 \cdot 3 = \frac{14}{9}$$

$$E(B) = \frac{1}{60} \int_0^{10} db \, b (b+1)$$

I get $E(X) = \frac{143}{18}$.

Comment: Would you be able to explain in more detail how you got the values for the probabilities in part a? That's the only part so far that I am confused on.

Comment: @NoName: I would be able to.  But how much help do you need?  I thought it was just in setting up the problems.  In any case, for $A$, consider the ratios of the area; for $B$, do you know how to work with a probability density function?

Comment: I sort of know how to deal with pdf's, but I'm not sure how you used the given one to find probabilities of B for part a. EDIT: Oh I see. If I need to find the P(B>2). Then I would integrate over the given function from 2 to 10 and that gives me 14/15

Comment: @NoName: that's correct.

Comment: Now I'm trying to get the ratio of the areas so I can find probabilities for the different A values, but I'm having a little trouble. So What I'm doing is is calculating the area for the whole thing and then subtracting to find each of the smaller parts, but they are all long numbers with lots of decimals. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @NoName: you don't need to compute the areas, just the ratio of the squares of the radii.  The inner one is just $(4/12)^2$; the center one is $(8^2-4^2)/12^2$, etc.

Comment: Great! Got it. Thanks for all the help.